# Return False if initialization of a class object has undesired values in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to return False if an Object instantiation does not have the appropriate values. As far as I know this is not possible to do this with an **init** method. Is there another method that I can use to check the values are return a bool value?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        if x == 0 and y == 0 and z == 0:
            return False
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

print(Test(0, 0, 0)) #should return False
```

Comment: Why aren't you throwing an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test(0,0,0)` is an invocation of a constructor and will always return an instance of the `Test` class.  Trying to return any value from `__init__` will result in a `TypeError`.

What you really want here is a [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  `TestFactory` provides a static method for creating tests which will return `None`, a more reasonable value for "invalid" objects, in your special case and otherwise just a plain test.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

class TestFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def create_test(x,y,z):
        if x == 0 and y == 0 and z == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return Test(x,y,z)

print(TestFactory.create_test(0,0,0))
```